# Mean of a given distribution

Tags: probability, integration, expectation

Find the mean of a distribution with given CDF:
$$F(x)=1-{1\over{1+bx^a}}, t>0$$

By definition: $$EX=\int_0^\infty xdF(x)=\int_0^\infty\frac{abx^a}{(1+bx^a)^2}dx $$

How can I solve this integral or Is there a simplest method?

Comment: You may try $\displaystyle E[X] = \int_0^{+\infty} 1 - F(x) dx$. Then try the substitution $y = 1 + bx^a$

Answer (score 1):

Let $b>0$ and $a>1$ (if $a\le 1$ the integral doesn't converge and the mean doesn't exist).

We have
$$
\Bbb E(X)=\int_0^\infty\left(1-F(x)\right)\mathrm d x=\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{1+bx^a}\mathrm d x=\frac{1}{b^{1/a}}\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{1+u^a}\mathrm d u
$$
after the substitution $b^{1/a}x=u$. Putting $u^a=z$, $\mathrm du=\frac{1}{a}z^{\frac{1}{a}-1}\mathrm dz $
we have
$$
\Bbb E(X)=\frac{1}{b^{1/a}}\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{1+u^a}\mathrm d u=\frac{1}{ab^{1/a}}\int_0^\infty \frac{z^{\frac{1}{a}-1}}{1+z}\mathrm d z=\frac{1}{ab^{1/a}}B\left(\frac{1}{a},1-\frac{1}{a}\right)
$$
where
[$B\left(x,y\right)$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.12.E3) is the Euler's Beta function. We have
$$
B\left(\frac{1}{a},1-\frac{1}{a}\right)=\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{a}\right)\Gamma\left(1-\frac{1}{a}\right)}{\Gamma\left(1\right)}=\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{a}\right)\Gamma\left(1-\frac{1}{a}\right)=\frac{\pi}{\sin\frac{\pi}{a}}
$$
and then
$$
\Bbb E(X)=\frac{1}{b^{1/a}}\frac{\pi/a}{\sin(\pi/a)}=\frac{1}{b^{1/a}\,\mathrm{Sinc}\left(\frac{\pi}{a}\right)}
$$

Comment: If $b>0$ the integrand of the next-to-last integral, $1/(1+bx^a),$ is bounded on $[0,1]$.  So that integral converges for all $a$, provided $b>0$.